# Fast Collision Detection for Circle Insertion into 2D Plane

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection

I know there are lots of posts about collision detection generally for sprites moving about a 2D plane, but my question is slightly different.

I'm inserting circles into a 2D plane.  The circles have variable radii.  I'm trying to optimize my method of finding a random position within the plane where I can insert a new circle without it colliding with any other circles already on the plane.  Right now I'm using a very "un-optimized" approach that simply generates a random point within the plane and then checks it against all the other circles on the plane.

Are there ways to optimize this?  For this particular app, the bounds of the plane can only hold 20-25 circles at a time and typically there are between 5-10 present.  As you would expect, when the number of circles approaches the max that can fit, you have to test many points before finding one that works.  It gets very slow.

Note: safeDistance is the radius of the circle I want to add to the plane.

Here's the code:

```
- (CGPoint)getSafePosition:(float)safeDistance {
// Point must be far enough from edges
// Point must be far enough from other sprites

CGPoint thePoint;
BOOL pointIsSafe = NO;

int sd = ceil(safeDistance);

while(!pointIsSafe) {

    self.pointsTested++; // DEBUG

    // generate a random point inside the plane boundaries to test
    thePoint = CGPointMake((arc4random() % ((int)self.manager.gameView.frame.size.width - sd*2)) + sd, 
                           (arc4random() % ((int)self.manager.gameView.frame.size.height - sd*2)) + sd);

    if(self.manager.gameView.sprites.count > 0) {
        for(BasicSprite *theSprite in self.manager.gameView.sprites) {

            // get distance between test point and the sprite position
            float distance = [BasicSprite distanceBetweenPoints:thePoint b:theSprite.position];

            // check if distance is less than the sum of the min safe distances of the two entities
            if(distance < (safeDistance + [theSprite minSafeDistance])) {
                // point not safe
                pointIsSafe = NO;
                break;
            }

            // if we get here, the point did not collide with the last tested point
            pointIsSafe = YES;
        }
    }
    else {
        pointIsSafe = YES;
    }
}

return thePoint;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not necceserily iphone related, I'm removing the iphone & objective-c tags so more ppl will join in

Comment: A 2D plane is a line, which is of infinite length. So you would have infinite space for your circles, unless you added the restriction which states they have to exactly touch each other. Or did you mean a line segment as opposed to an infinite line?

Comment: @Mads: "A 2D plane is a line" -- what? Obviously, the OP is asking about a rectangular region of fixed, finite size in the plane. You know, like the screen on an iPhone, for example.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Heh, feel free to call me an idiot. But I honestly found that ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Subdivide your window into `w` by `h` blocks.  You'll be maintaining a `w` by `h` array, `dist`.  `dist[x][y]` contains the size of the largest circle that can be centred at (x, y).  (You can use pixels as blocks, although we'll be updating the entire array with each circle placed, so you may want to choose larger blocks for improved speed, at the cost of slightly reduced packing densities.)

### Initialisation

Initially, set all `dist[x][y]` to `min(x, y, w - x, h - y)`.  This encodes the limits given by the bounding box that is the window.

### Update procedure

Every time you add a circle to the window, say one positioned at `(a, b)` with radius `r`, you need to update *all* elements of `dist`.

The update required for each position `(x, y)` is:

```
dist[x][y] = min(dist[x][y], sqrt((x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2) - r);
```

(Obviously, `^2` here means squaring, not XOR.)  Basically, we are saying: "Set dist[x][y] to the minimum distance to the circle just placed, unless the situation is already worse than that."  `dist` values for points inside the circle just placed will be negative, but that doesn't matter.

### Finding the next location

Then, when you want to insert the next circle of radius `q`, just scan through `dist` looking for a location with `dist` value >= `q`.  (If you want to randomly choose such a location, find the complete list of valid locations and then randomly choose one.)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, with only 20-25 circles, you're not going to get much of a speed boost by using a fancier algorithm or data structure (e.g. a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree)).  [Everything is fast for small n](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000957.html).

Are you absolutely sure this is the bottleneck in your application?  Have you profiled?  If yes, then the way you're going to speed this up is through microoptimization, not through advanced algorithms.  Are you making lots of iterations through the while loop because most of the plane is unsafe?

Comment: It's not the collision detection itself that slows the application down. It's the random jumping with the point!

Answer (score 0):

You could split your plane in lots of little rectangles (slightly [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)-related) and save which rectangles are hit by at least one of the circles. 
When you look for a insertion-point, you'll just have to look for some "empty" ones (which doesn't need any random jumps and is possible in constant time).

The number and constellation of rectangles can be computed by the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Just an outline, since this solution is fairly involved.

If you want to guarantee you always find a place to put a circle if it's possible, you can do the following.  Consider each existing circle C.  We will try to find a location where we can place the new circle so that it is touching C.  For each circle D (other than C) that is sufficiently close to C, there will be a range of angles where placing a new circle at one of those angles around C will make it intersect with D.  Some geometry will give you that range.  Similarly, for each of the four boundaries that are close enough to C, there will be a range of angles where placing a new circle at one of those angles will make it intersect with the boundary.  If all these intervals cover all 360 degrees around C, then you cannot place a circle adjacent to C, and you will have to try the next circle, until there are no more candidates for C.  If you find a place to put the new circle, you can move it some random distance away from C so that all your new circles do not have to be adjacent to an existing circle if that is not necessary.